# jQuery file upload plugin - looping autouploads

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm trying to be able to change the background image of a div via file upload. I have everything working for the first iteration. But the 2nd attempt to select a file and change the background doesn't work (you don't get the alert popup, and the filename doesn't change in the demo code below). You have to refresh the page to reset and start all over.

Demo code is here:
http://product-review-guru.com/Lab/jq-file-upload/

Plugin GitHub:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I'm hoping someone with some experience with this plugin can set me straight in a minute instead of me searching all day, haha!

UPDATE:

Ok, so here's the culprit:

```
                that._transition(data.context).done(
                    function () {
                        if ((that._trigger('added', e, data) !== false) &&
                                (options.autoUpload || data.autoUpload) &&
                                data.autoUpload !== false && data.isValidated) {
                                alert("su bmit");
                            data.submit();
                        }
                    }

                );
```

If I take the data.submit() out of the if statement and .done(), I get close to the desired functionality, with the exception of the progress bar during upload.  Here's the kicker... I output every condition for iteration #1, and #2 .. and the values for each condition are exactly the same ... UNLESS somehow the type changed on one of the conditions making it the if evaluate to false ... I'm stumped!